# How am I supposed to sync music with my Lumia Phone these days?

Tags: 8.1, sync, music, windows-10

I have a Lumia 1020 running WP8.1.
I was used to using "Windows Phone app for Desktop" on Windows 7 to sync my music to the phone from my hard disk.

It seems in Windows 10 I should be using "Phone Companion" but this doesn't actually seem to *do* anything except tell me to use File Explorer. As well, now there is Groove Music, XBox music as well as Media Player.

What is the 'correct' way - if there is such a thing - to sync music to my phone? Ideally it would know what was on the device hence the word 'sync' rather than 'copy'.

Comment: With my Lumia 1020 I only ever used File Explorer or Windows Media Player - can you expand on *how* you want it to sync? Did you mean to download new photos from your phone, or push new content to your phone?

Comment: if your phone is running on 8.1 , u could connect it to pc using usb cable, phone would be recognized and also you still can use windows phone app for your device

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to sync music between your computer and your phone running Windows 8.1 or 10.

### Sync with OneDrive

If you are logged in with the same MS account both into your PC and phone, you can simply drag & drop files into your OneDrive *Music* folder. All of your files will be available in Groove. (By default it will stream the music, but you can download all synced tracks with one tap.)

Note:

- files synced in OneDrive are also available in the [Groove Web Player](https://music.microsoft.com/).
- files deleted from OneDrive won't be deleted from your phone.
- this is likely the most easiest way.

### Copy files from PC to the phone when it's connected

When you connect your phone with the USB cable it will be in file-transfer mode by default. You can open your phone storage with the File Explorer and copy your music from your PC to the phone's *Music* folder.

Note:

- The phone needs to be unlocked to allows file transfer.
- If the phone gets locked during copy, it will stop the file transfer.

### Download the music to your phone and copy it to the music folder

Windows Mobile 10 includes a file explorer by default, for Windows Phone 8.1 you can download [one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/files/9wzdncrfj3pl) created by Microsoft. Once you have a file explorer you can simply download any music to your phone, then copy it from the *Downloads* folder into the *Music* folder.

Note:

- On WP8.1 your phone will open music files in the music player to stream it by default. (You can download it from there somehow. I already have W10M, so I can't check.)